# Google Map make blur effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I'm using this example code to overlay something on a Google map.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Map Test</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
      }
      .txt {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 150px;
        padding: 30px 50px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
        z-index: 99;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <iframe src="http://www.apps-tube.com/ip-lookup/google-map.php?xy=14.4673541,78.8241339" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" id="gmap" style="width:746px;height:380px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="txt">Country name</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get this result [Text automatically `blurred`]

[image]

But I want the result without the `blur effect` like the image below.

[image]

Please help me remove this blur effect. Visit [this link](http://test.easy-digital.com/gmap/page.php) for an example page.

Note: I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: I can't tell the difference between the two images... can you describe the change you want to make in a little more detail?

Comment: i can't see any difference either

Comment: accidentally uploaded the same image??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jooxa just ignore this error. This problem is only happens on Google browsers (version 27 or below).

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code in Google Crome browser, you are calling **map.php** in iframe,

I have seen the way you are calling map, its calling only images ( I mean its maps Image API,

you find another way using [Google Maps API Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/)

Refer documentation and get through your problem,

within the same solution there is no inbuilt way to deal with this problem as the data is coming in form of pre-compiled images.

Thank you,